# How to stop event listener till I click Ok on sweet alert message?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to halt my event listener till I click on the ok button of sweet alert. In my code when sweet alert pop up with `game over` and `ok` button in it.  I wanted to make sure to halt my event listener till I click on `ok` button in my pop up. right now my game is playable in the background of my sweet alert pop up 
 which I don't want to do. 
Here is my code.

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    console.log('hi')
    var allowedKeys = {
        37: 'left',
        38: 'up',
        39: 'right',
        40: 'down'
    };

    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});

class Player {

    static lifeCount = 3;

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';

    }

    handleInput(key) {
        if (key === 'left' && this.x > 4) {
            this.x -= 100;
        }
        if (key === 'right' && this.x < 400) {
            this.x += 100;
        }
        if (key === 'up' && this.y > -20) {
            this.y -= 85;
        }
        if (key === 'down' && this.y < 400) {
            this.y += 85;
        }
    }

    update() {
        if (this.y === -25) {
            console.log('this is win')
            this.x = 200;
            this.y = 400;
            swal({
                title: "Good job!",
                text: "You won this level",
                icon: "success",
                button: "Play next!",
            });
            levelCount++;
            level.innerHTML = `Level - ${levelCount}`;
        }
    }

    render() {
        ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
    }

    respawn() {
        swal({
            title: "Try again!",
            text: "bugs are deadly",
            icon: "error",
            button: "Play again!",
        });
        this.x = 200;
        this.y = 400;

        if (Player.lifeCount < 1) {
            levelCount = 1;
        }

        Player.lifeCount--;
        if (Player.lifeCount < 3) {
            img.removeChild(img.firstElementChild);
        }
    }
}
player.respawn(); // here when sweet alert get executed I wanted to halt my 
                 //event listener operation till I click Ok button in sweet 
                 //alert .
```

Comment: share your sweet alert code from where and how it calls?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove the event listener whenever your sweet alert gets executed, and then after the alert is closed you can add the listener back. You would need to refactor your callback function for `addEventListener` to be its own function, and then pass it to to your eventListener. Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', eventListenerCallback);
```

And then when your sweet alert fires inside of `respawn` you can remove the listener:

```
document.removeEventListener('keyup', eventListenerCallback);
```